# Threads not being accessed by pylance, and any way to stop a thread? Python

Tags: python

My code

```
    import time

    answer = None

    def check():

        #Global Variable Definitions

        global outOfTime
        global answer

        #Variable Fixup

        outOfTime = 2
        timevalue = 0

        #Set Time Dependant On Level

        if difficulty == "EASY":
            timevalue = 300 / level
        elif difficulty == "MEDIUM":
            timevalue = 150 / level
        elif difficulty == "HARD":
            timevalue = 5 / level
        else:
            print("ERROR!")
            time.sleep(2) #Incase Of No Difficulty
            quizStartup()

        print("You Have", round(timevalue), "Seconds")

        time.sleep(timevalue) #Timer
        if answer == None:
            outOfTime = 1

    from threading import Thread 
    t = Thread(target = check).start 

    answer = input("Answer: ")
```

When I run this code, its being working forever but now the thread is not accessed by pylance. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Also is there anyway to stop this thread later on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.start is not a property, you need to call it like a function, t = Thread(target=).start()
to stop a thread, the proper way is with flags

Comment: you know anyway to stop a thread, Works btw.

Comment: there a few ways to. You need to set a flag, like while bool == False: #run thread then on a certain condition you can set bool to True so itll stop the thread